# D3 - Appending SVG based on JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

In my attached [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raj_aiyer/y8610g56/), you will find a variable dataset that is a JSON object with a nested array that contains three different JSON objects. The code below aims to append a circle element to the canvas for each of these objects. The x position is based on a field in the JSON and upon clicking on the circle, prints another field in the console (you'll notice this JSON data is of Tweets pulled from the Twitter API).

However, only one circle is being shown with this code when you run it:

```
canvas.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", (d.Followers)/20)
      .attr("cy", 200)
      .attr("r", 30)
      .attr("fill", "#42f459")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2.5)
      .on("mouseover", mouseOn)
        .on("mouseout", mouseOff)
      .on('mousedown.log', function (d) {
        console.log(d.Tweet);
      });
```

How does this code need to change to show circles for all the data as opposed to just one circle? Clicking on it and seeing what prints seems to indicate that it is only appending a circle for the last JSON object in the dataset.

Any tips you can give would be most appreciated. I feel like this is due to a lack of understanding of what data() and enter() actually mean in the context of D3 and as I am new to it. Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.Favourites = d.Favourites;
        d.Default = d["Has Default Profile Image"];  
        d.Followers = d["Number of followers"];
        d.Timestamp = d.Timestamp;
        d.Tweet = d.Tweet;
        d.Url = d["Tweet URL"]
        d.Description = d["User Description"];
        d.Location = d["User Location"];
        d.Verified = d["User Verified"];
        d.Retweets = d.Retweets;
        d.Username = d.Username;
 });

       canvas.selectAll("circle")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("cx", function(d){return d.Followers/20})
          .attr("cy", 200)
          .attr("r", 30)
          .attr("fill", "#42f459")
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("stroke-width", 2.5)
          .on("mouseover", mouseOn)
            .on("mouseout", mouseOff)
          .on('mousedown.log', function (d) {
            console.log(d.Tweet);
          });

          function mouseOn(d, i) {
            d3.select(this).attr({
              fill: "#42f4ee"
            });
          }

          function mouseOff(d, i) {
            d3.select(this).attr({
              fill: "#42f459"
            });
          }
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zs00qwa8/4/). First you needed to setup the data, and once the data is ready, then loop through each item and draw the circles.

Comment: Thank you so much John! I appreciate your help. So I get now you have to setup the data first. Do you have to use ForEach for this? What if you wanted to display the n circles at a time? When you call function(d) a second time, does that replace the data already there? I think I am a little unsure on what this d represents.

Comment: This section is essentially the for loop, everything after enter is done for each object in the array. 
 
      canvas.selectAll("circle")
          .data(data)
          .enter()   ----- do something for each object ---------          

function(d) passes in the current object to a function, which you can use to interrogate the object and return values based on its properties.

Comment: I see, thank you. One last question (sorry): so let's say I wanted to create circles only for the first n JSON objects. Would this involve replacing the ForEach block with the following? - for (var i = 0; i<n; i++) { function(d) {  d.Favourites = d.Favourites; ... }. I tried this but it didn't seem to allow this syntax. Can function(d) not be used like this in a for loop?

Comment: You need to manipulate the data array before passing it to d3. Create a new data array, var dataSubset = data.slice(0, 3);. This returns the first 3 objects. Then use dataSubset, e.g.  .data(dataSubset). See more about slice here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp.